# Show Mobile component ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BigText extends Component {

  render() {
 
    return ( 
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1 className="row px-2">Big Text Notification</h1>
          <hr />
          <div className="row px-1 py-2 animated fadeIn">
  
                <div className="px-1" style={{ width:50 + '%' }}><br />

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <input type="text"
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Title"
                       name="title"
                       />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea 
                      className="form-control" 
                      placeholder="Text"
                      name="text"
                      />
                    </div>

                    <div className="mb-1">
                      <textarea
                       className="form-control" 
                       placeholder="Summary"
                       name="summary"
                       />
                    </div>

                    <br />

                    <div className="row px-2" >
                      <div>
                        <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-info"  onClick={this.handleClick} >Save</button>
                      </div>
                      <div className="px-1">
                        <button className="nav-link btn btn-block btn-danger"> Cancel</button>
                      </div>
                    </div><br />

                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    )
    
  }
}

export default BigText;
```

i had added the code snippet
What I'm doing is I'm trying to add a Mobile frame as component on side of the fields so that whatever i write in the fields will be shown in that mobile being shown as the component on the screen
so i wanted to know how to add that mobile and how to show text in it as well

Comment: i don't know how to do that that's why i asked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43385506/how-to-put-image-as-border-in-css-in-react-js